# Required field validator for User control not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

Hi I have created user control for re-sizable text box.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelText" runat="server" CssClass="frameText">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxResizable" CssClass="noborder" Width="100%"
    Height="100%" TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ResizableControlExtender ID="ResizableTextBoxExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="PanelText"
ResizableCssClass="resizingText" HandleCssClass="handleText" OnClientResizing="OnClientResizeText" />
```

And have created Validator property for this control like:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
 public partial class ResizableTextBoxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ public string Validator
{
    get { return this.TextBoxResizable.Text; }
} 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
}
```

In aspx page I am using this control like:

```
<uc1:ResizableTextBoxControl ID="tbDescription" MinimumHeight="50" MinimumWidth="100"
 MaximumHeight="300" MaximumWidth="400" runat="server" onKeyPress="javascript:Count(this,1500);" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this,1500);" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ></uc1:ResizableTextBoxControl>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDescription" runat="server" controlToValidate="tbDescription" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ErrorMessage="Description" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When I click on submit, "tbDescription" does not appear to be mandatory.
What can be wrong with the code?

**EDIT**

Ok...I got what was the problem, one control was hidden, and required field validator for that control was not disabled, I did it using jquery and now everything is fine except asterics.. I dont understand why asterics are not visible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all the trouble,

There was one control on page which was hidden and required field validator for that control was not disabled. I disabled it using jQuery like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$("#<%=TextBoxResizable.ClientID %>").is(":visible")) {
        ValidatorEnable(<%=rfvTextBoxResizable.ClientID %>, false);
    }
})
```

Asteric is visible after placing required field validator outside Panel.

Answer (score 1):

try placing your validator to your controlle especially if you just try to validate one textbox

```
   <asp:Panel ID="PanelText" runat="server" CssClass="frameText">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxResizable" CssClass="noborder" Width="100%"
    Height="100%" TextMode="MultiLine">

    </asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
ID="rfvDescription" runat="server" controlToValidate="TextBoxResizable"
 ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" 
ErrorMessage="Description" Text="*" 
ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True">

</asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ResizableControlExtender ID="ResizableTextBoxExtender"
 runat="server" TargetControlID="PanelText"

    ResizableCssClass="resizingText" HandleCssClass="handleText OnClientResizing="OnClientResizeText" />
```

in to the user controller it might not be recognized after the page is rendered.

Comment: I tried this,  However, I want an asteric to be visible when I click on submit. Which is not visible and even after entering data in all fields 'btnSubmit_Click' even is never called...

Comment: @user1181942 Maybe you should put asteric as error message and not description and you are using validation group make sure the submit button is the same validation group

Answer (score 0):

try using **Page.IsValid** in your Submit button event.

```
if (!Page.IsValid) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: it is already there...however, Submit button event is not firing .